# I am creating a dictionary from 2 columns. A value in my table needs to be split into lat and long and then placed back into the dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

This is the information I am placing into my dictionary.

[image]

Latitude and longitude needs to be split.
The code I have tried to use is as follows:

```
for filelist in glob.glob(vol_rawdata_path):
    df = pd.read_excel(filelist,header=None,sheet_name="Summary")
    df.rename(columns={0:'Name'}, inplace = True)
    df.rename(columns={1:'definition'}, inplace = True)
    df = df.dropna()
    coordinate = df.iat[8,1].split(',')
    latitude = coordinate[0]
    longitude = coordinate[1]
    volSumDiction = pd.Series(df.definition.values,index=df.Name).to_dict()
    values = list(volSumDiction)
    values = values[7]
    print(values)
```

I understand that calling out coordinate, latitude, and longitude is the wrong approach, but i couldn't find a solution to this hurdle.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Looks like you are extracting the lat and lng but not assigning it to your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the values on each line into the dictionary by accessing it like this,

```
for filelist in glob.glob(vol_rawdata_path):
    df = pd.read_excel(filelist,header=None,sheet_name="Summary")
    df.rename(columns={0:'Name'}, inplace = True)
    df.rename(columns={1:'definition'}, inplace = True)
    df = df.dropna()
    volSumDiction = pd.Series(df.definition.values,index=df.Name).to_dict()
    coordinate = df.iat[8,1].split(',')
    volSumDiction['latitude'] = coordinate[0]
    volSumDiction['longitude'] = coordinate[1]
    values = list(volSumDiction)
    values = values[7]
    print(values)
```

Comment: however, when i do that I cannot append data to the volSumDiction.   
    'volSumDiction["latitude"] = data[0]
    volSumDiction["longitude"] = data[1]
    volSumTable = volSumTable.append(volSumDiction, ignore_index=True)'

Comment: @joshuah9 updated my code again. does this work?